# How to get public_dns_name according to ec2 resource instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Now I want to get the public_dns_name, and then log on to an instance of aws to get the CPU utilization. I know that I can check it with cloudwatch, but now I don't want to rely on the function provided by amazon to check it directly based on Linux. How can I get it?

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',
                     aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS.get("aws_access_key_id"),
                     aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS.get("aws_secret_access_key"),
                     region_name=settings.AWS.get("region_name"))

user_data_script = """#cloud-config
   runcmd:
    - sudo systemctl start docker
    - cd /srv/app/kfquantum
    - sudo docker run --env broker=%s \
                      --env result=redis://10.0.0.245:6379/0 \
                      --env host=kf-db.cluster-crietao0wrdu.rds.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn \
                      --env user=db \
                      --env pw=y6y83aGagY8hgXZ \
                      -w /kfquantum -d --restart unless-stopped --name kf-celery kf-celery \
                      celery -A kfquantum worker --pool=solo -l info
   """ % settings.BROKER_URL
instance_type = "c5.large"
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeSize': 8
            },
        },
    ],
    ImageId="ami-09feea664bfc54194",
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    Placement={'AvailabilityZone': 'cn-northwest-1a'},
    InstanceType=instance_type,
    UserData=user_data_script,
    NetworkInterfaces=[
        {
            'DeviceIndex': 0,
            'SubnetId': "subnet-093161e8b00deb367",
            'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True
        },
    ]
)
instance = instance[0]
print("1",instance.private_ip_address)
print("2",instance.public_dns_name)
```

Console

```
1,10.0.0.73
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
instance= instance[0]
print('***Success!! instance:', instance.id, 'created, and instance-state-name:', instance.state['Name'])           

instance.wait_until_running()           
instance.reload()

print('***instance:', instance.id, 'is now up, and instance-state-name:', instance.state['Name'])
print('***private ipa:', instance.private_ip_address)
print('***public ipa:', instance.public_dns_name)
```

Hope it helps...
r0ck

Answer (score 0):

The value for `public_dns_name` is not assigned yet.

This could be due to

1. The instance is not `running` yet. You are trying to fetch the DNS name as soon as the `create_instances` method is invoked. It takes a few seconds for the instance to reach `running` state. The `public_dns_name` is not available until the instance reaches `running` state. Check for the instance state and wait for it to be running before trying to get the Public DNS Name.

An easy fix without disturbing the rest of your code would be,

**Update:**
The `instance` object must be reloaded after the waiter for the updated instance attributes to be detected.

```
instance = instance[0]
instance.wait_until_running()
instance.reload()
print("1",instance.private_ip_address)
print("2",instance.public_dns_name)
```

2. DNS hostnames are not enabled in your VPC.

Comment: Thx, I tried, I saw in the aws console, 3 seconds later , this instance has been running, and then I took a few seconds to get public_dns_name, still did not get. I would like to ask how can I get to public_dns_name through the methods of boto.resource and create_instances? Is there any code for reference? (I know the instance created by client is relatively easy to get.but resource method is hard, it is high-level aws instance )

Comment: Did it have a public DNS name assigned when you checked in the console?

Comment: Yes,it does have the public DNS name ,just like this ec2-52-82-27-49.cn-northwest-1.compute.amazonaws.com.cn. now I wanna get this from my python code.

Comment: Sure, before that can you update your code in the question to show how you waited for the instance to reach the running state before trying to fetch the DNS?

Comment: ec2 = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='',
                        aws_secret_access_key='',
                        region_name='').resource("ec2")
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running'], }])

    for i in instances:
        print(i.public_dns_name)

Comment: Now I can get it this way, is that ok?

Comment: No, this again will not wait for the instance to reach the running state. Instead this will list out all the instances that are currently in running state. Updating the answer

Comment: I know. This method does not create a new instance, but I can get the data I want with the instance id based on this method. If can't get it, That means it's not in a running state, and if I get it, it works.Thank you for your reference

Comment: I added instance.wait_until_running()
I tried, but it didn't work,
Did you succeed?

Comment: No errors, but still return None, need to add "instance.reload()" , thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah.. missed it!